# How to resolve throttled errors when retrieving secrets from Azure Keyvault in Azure Synapse?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-synapse

We have created an orchestration of pipelines with configurable linked datasources. These datasources have a parameter where we can enter the name of a secret and it will search in our keyvault for that secret. This is all configured in the UI. No programming necessary. And it works beautifully.

For some reason however it sometimes stops working when looking up secrets to write to an sql-table. And when it stops working, it stops all ETL-processes.

The error we receive is:

*Failed to get the secret from key vault, secretName: xxxxx, secretVersion: , vaultBaseUrl: https://xxxxxxx.vault.azure.net/. The error message is: Acquire MI token from AAD failed. ErrorCode: request_throttled, Message: Your app has been throttled by AAD due to too many requests. To avoid this, cache your tokens see https://aka.ms/msal-net-throttling..*

I don't see huge numbers of requests in the logging. I can't find anything suggesting this is a common problem.

I'm looking for either an answer on why this is happening so I can think of a solution OR possible solutions.

One possible solution could be to retrieve the secret in the beginning of  the ETL-process and passing it on as a parameter to the proper activity. However, from a security standpoint that is not very safe as parameters are passed on and logged in clear text.